# How to match Value from string in Mysql PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table `methodology` in mysql where a column contain values like `1,2,3,4,5,6` or `3,4,6`  or `25,4,7,8` in multiple row.

Now in my scenario i have a company which contain id `6` and i want to Match this value with methodology table value. But i don't have any idea how i can do it.

I am trying that first it get all values from methodology table one by one and after that match value of company.

can anyone please help me??

Comment: Your tables are not properly normalized, while it's perfectly fine to store comma separated values in columns in most cases, it's not fine when you have to search for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `FIND_IN_SET(your_id, columnname)` function.

Query will be like

```
SELECT * FROM
methodology 
where FIND_IN_SET(your_id, columnname)
```

For more details about function please refer : http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-find_in_set-function.php

Answer (score 0):

Use `LIKE` from mysql queries.

An example :
`SELECT row FROM my_table WHERE my_column LIKE %6%`

Comment: what if the list contains value like `66` but no `6` there?

Comment: you are right @1000111. like is precise in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use find_in_set function

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on @matthiasbe's incomplete answer, if you want to use `LIKE`, you should do as follows :

```
SELECT * FROM methodology WHERE companies LIKE '%,6,%' OR companies LIKE '6,%' OR companies LIKE '%,6'
```

This will match all rows where `companies` either has `,6,` in its value or begins with `6,` or ends with `,6`.

This is far from being a perfect solution (both in clarity of the code and execution time), I'm just listing the options, hope it helps.

Comment: And what if `6` is the only element in the list?

Comment: Hadn't thought of that, just add `OR companies = '6'` at the end of the request.